Proof that convergence in probability is not locally convex
On Wikipedia, it is stated that the topology induced by convergence in probability is not locally convex. However, no proof nor reference is provided, and I couldn't find anything on Google.
I think it must have something to do with the cardinality of the subbasis: Since convergence in probability is induced by a translation-invariant metric, if its topology was locally convex, it would have to be induced by countably many semi-norms, and we know that an equivalent metric can be defined in terms of these semi-norms. However, I wasn't really able to get to anything from there.
Can anyone provide a short proof or maybe a reference?

As stated in the Wikipedia article you cited, this is because on $L^0([0, 1])$, equipped with the topology of convergence in probability, the only continuous linear functional is the zero functional. Indeed, let $\varphi: L^0([0, 1]) \to \mathbb{C}$ be a continuous linear functional. Let the natural inclusion map $L^1([0, 1]) \to L^0([0, 1])$ be denoted by $\pi$. Then we note that $\varphi \circ \pi$ is a continuous linear functional on $L^1([0, 1])$ (w.r.t. to the usual norm), since, if $f_n \to f$ in $L^1$, then $f_n \to f$ in probability as well. As $\varphi$ is continuous w.r.t. the topology of convergence in probability, we have $\varphi \circ \pi(f_n) \to \varphi \circ \pi(f)$, so $\varphi \circ \pi$ is continuous on $L^1([0, 1])$.
Now, as the dual space of $L^1([0, 1])$ is $L^\infty([0, 1])$, we must have $g \in L^\infty([0, 1])$ s.t. $\varphi(f) = \int gf \, dm$ for all $f \in L^1([0, 1])$. Assume $g \neq 0$, then for some $\epsilon > 0$, the set $A_\epsilon = \{x \in [0, 1]: |g(x)| > \epsilon\}$ is not null. Thus, we may write $A_\epsilon = \sqcup_{i=1}^\infty B_i$ for some pairwise disjoint sequence of non-null sets $B_i$. Let $f_n(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1_{B_i}(x)}{m(B_i)g(x)}$. Since $|g(x)| > \epsilon$ on $A_\epsilon$, we see that $f_n \in L^\infty([0, 1]) \subset L^1([0, 1])$, so,
$$\varphi(f_n) = \int f_ng \, dm = n$$
On the other hand, $f_n \to f := \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1_{B_i}(x)}{m(B_i)g(x)}$ a.e., so in probability as well by Egorov’s theorem. Thus, $\varphi(f) = \lim_n \varphi(f_n) = \infty$, contradicting the fact that $\varphi$ is a well-defined linear functional on $L^0([0, 1])$. Hence, it must be the case that $g = 0$ a.e., whence,
$$\varphi(f) = 0, \forall f \in L^1([0, 1])$$
But $L^1([0, 1])$ is dense in $L^0([0, 1])$ - indeed, any measurable function can be approximated a.e., and therefore also in probability, by a sequence of simple functions, and simple functions are in $L^1([0, 1])$. Thus, by continuity, $\varphi = 0$.
This implies the topology on $L^0([0, 1])$ is not locally convex, as otherwise $L^0([0, 1])$ would admit nontrivial continuous linear functionals, per Hahn-Banach theorem.

For some reason I completely missed the fact that $L^1$ convergence already implies convergence in probability in the first version of this answer. That oversight has now been fixed and the answer was simplified somewhat as a result.
